# How do I add syntax coloring to my C++ source code in beamer

Tags: beamer, listings, color

I have just learned how to insert source code into `beamer` with the `listings` package. 
However I dont know how to go about adding any syntax coloring on the C++ source code.

How do I do that?

Here is the code I am currently using for source code insertion.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
 \setbeamercovered{transparent}
%\usepackage{pxfonts}
\usepackage{listings}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Inserting source code}
  \lstset{language=C++}
\begin{lstlisting}
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<iostream>
    int main(void)
    {
    printf("Hello World\n");
    return 0;
    }
\end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

This is an example with C++ code highlighted; the two frames show the difference between adopting the typewriter font and not:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
 \setbeamercovered{transparent}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

% Using typewriter font: \ttfamily inside \lstset
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Inserting source code}
\lstset{language=C++,
                basicstyle=\ttfamily,
                keywordstyle=\color{blue}\ttfamily,
                stringstyle=\color{red}\ttfamily,
                commentstyle=\color{green}\ttfamily,
                morecomment=[l][\color{magenta}]{\#}
}
\begin{lstlisting}
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<iostream>
    // A comment
    int main(void)
    {
    printf("Hello World\n");
    return 0;
    }
\end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Inserting source code without setting typewriter}
\lstset{language=C++,
                keywordstyle=\color{blue},
                stringstyle=\color{red},
                commentstyle=\color{green},
                morecomment=[l][\color{magenta}]{\#}
}
\begin{lstlisting}
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<iostream>
    // A comment
    int main(void)
    {
    printf("Hello World\n");
    return 0;
    }
\end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Notice that there's no difference from Beamer or standard document in using `listings`. The package guide explains in detail how to do this, but you can also find information looking at the apposite tag [listing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/listings) on this site. The command `\ttfamily` sets the given style in typewriter.

Comment: Thank you. One question. Could you explain what this "ttfamily " is? Is it a specific font?

Comment: Yes, it's the typewriter font.